# Command line programs on windows randomly freeze. Ctrl-C reactivates them

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I am writing a simple program in Java, and sometimes it randomly freezes and does not respond. when I try to end it with Ctrl-C instead of quitting, the program springs back to life and starts working fine again. I am not posting my code because I have noticed this behavior with other command line programs on Windows, so it does not appear to be anything specific to my code. The program will eventually be running 24/7 on a headless server, so you can see why it would be a serious issue if it just stopped working every now and then. Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without any code there's no way to tell

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you solved it? What was the cause?

Comment: Yes, I needed to disable "quick edit mode" in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit like perhaps a selection issue: If you make a selection in the console window, it freezes console output. The next time an application attempts to flush to the console it will stall until the selection is cleared. Pressing ctrl-c will copy the selection and clear it, allowing the flush to complete and the application to continue to run. Any keypress in the console window should clear the selection though, and it sounds like only ctrl-c is working for you.

If that's not what the issue is, your next best bet the next time you see this would be to open up a native debugger (e.g. Windbg) or a java debugger and attach to the process you're running in the console process to see what is doing the waiting. It's likely that something you're calling is triggering a spurious getch / readline / etc. A debugger should make the source of the stall obvious. If you need help deciphering the stack once you have one, I might be able to help. Just paste it into this thread.

Ben